# Django view: Count data from model contained in [ ]

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

I'm working in django 1.8.

A column called `diagnosis_option` in table `Diagnosis` contains the following:

```
[u'b-thalassaemia syndromes']
[u'b-thalassaemia syndromes', u'Sickle cell syndromes']
[u'b-thalassaemia syndromes']
[u'Sickle cell syndromes']
[u'Red cell enzyme disorders']
```

I'm using the code below in `views.py` but I got no results. How I count all fields that contain the string `b-thalassaemia syndromes`?

```
total_patients_beta = Diagnosis.objects.filter(diagnosis_option__in='b-thalassaemia syndromes').count()
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What type of field is `diagnosis_option`?

Comment: @AKS No I get no errors. I only get `0`. The type of `diagnosis_option` is `models.CharField( max_length=150)`.

Comment: I don't understand. If it is a `CharField` then why do you have `list` values in this?

Comment: @AKS Because I have multiselection in my gui and I can store more than one values.

Comment: I wonder if you can store `list` values in `CharField`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Temporary Fix

Unfortunately you have a poorly designed database, the way to get the count is with this query.

```
total_patients_beta = Diagnosis.objects.filter(
  diagnosis_option__contains='b-thalassaemia syndromes').count()
```

This results in a LIKE '%b-thalassaemia%' query which cannot use indexes on most databases.

### Real Fix

You need to normalize your database. It's almost never a good idea to store comma separated values in a database column. Though some databases most notably postgresql support Array data types, those data types are not designed to be searched in.

> Tip: Arrays are not sets; searching for specific array elements can be
>   a sign of database misdesign. Consider using a separate table with a
>   row for each item that would be an array element. This will be easier
>   to search, and is likely to scale better for a large number of
>   elements.

source: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html

You probably need a model acalled DiagnosisOption with a foreign key or many to many relationship to diagnosis.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and your suggestion! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Glad to have been of help